# Spark to read Cassandra

Tags: pyspark, cassandra, aws-glue

Hi I am trying to extract data from Cassandra using AWS Glue and writing PySpark Code. Below is the code and gave me error. Please suggest me how i can import classes/drivers.

I want to extract from Cassandra and create files into S3 Buckets.

```
#from awsglue.transforms import sys
import sys
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])
sparkContext = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sparkContext)
sparkSession = glueContext.spark_session
#Use the CData JDBC driver to read Cassandra data from the Customer table into a DataFrame ##Note the populated JDBC URL and driver class name

#source_df = sparkSession.read.format("jdbc").option("url","jdbc:cassandra:RTK=5246...;Database=MyCassandraDB;Port=7000;Server=db-datastax02c-dc2.stage.impello.co.uk;")\.option("dbtable","reads_by_received_date").option("driver","cdata.jdbc.cassandra.CassandraDriver").load()*/

#df = glueContext.read.format("jdbc").option("driver", jdbc_driver_name).option("url", db_url).option("dbtable", table_name).option("user", db_username).option("password", db_password).load()

glueJob = Job(glueContext)
glueJob.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

testdf = sparkSession.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")\
                    .option("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "server")\
                    .options(table="reads_by_received_date",keyspace="keyspace")\
                    .option("spark.cassandra.auth.username", "username") \
                    .option("spark.cassandra.auth.password", "username") \
                    .load()\
#.select(*)\
#.where( "received_year in (2020)")\
#.cache()
                    
##Convert DataFrames to AWS Glue's DynamicFrames Object
dynamic_dframe = DynamicFrame.fromDF(testdf, glueContext, "dynamic_df")
##Write the DynamicFrame as a file in CSV format to a folder in an S3 bucket.
datatransfer = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = dynamic_dframe\
                                                                    , connection_type = "s3"\
                                                                    , connection_options = {"path": "s3://bucket/"}\
                                                                    , format = "csv"\
                                                                    , transformation_ctx = "datasink4"
                                                            )

glueJob.commit()
```

Error:

```
Aug 28, 2020, 4:43:27 PM Pending execution
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/tmp/CassandraToS3", line 27, in <module> .option("spark.cassandra.auth.password", "password") \ File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 172, in load return self._df(self._jreader.load()) File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__ answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name) File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco return f(*a, **kw) File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value format(target_id, ".", name), value) py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o75.load. : java.io.IOException: Failed to open native connection to Cassandra at {} :: Could not reach any contact point, make sure you've provided valid addresses (showing first 1 nodes, use getAllErrors() for more): Node(endPoint=/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=4f522a41): [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ConnectionInitException: [s0|control|connecting...] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): failed to send request (java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException)] at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$CassandraConnector$$createSession(CassandraConnector.scala:181) at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$3.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:169) at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$3.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:169) at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.createNewValueAndKeys(RefCountedCache.scala:32) at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.syncAcquire(RefCountedCache.scala:69) at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.acquire(RefCountedCache.scala:57) at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.openSession(CassandraConnector.scala:89) at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:111) at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.partitioner.dht.TokenFactory$.forSystemLocalPartitioner(TokenFactory.scala:98) at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSourceRelation$.apply(CassandraSourceRelation.scala:680) at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:57) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:318) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:167) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244) at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357) at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282) at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132) at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79) at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.AllNodesFailedException: Could not reach any contact point, make sure you've provided valid addresses (showing first 1 nodes, use getAllErrors() for more): Node(endPoint=/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=4f522a41): [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ConnectionInitException: [s0|control|connecting...] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): failed to send request (java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException)] at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.AllNodesFailedException.copy(AllNodesFailedException.java:141) at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.util.concurrent.CompletableFutures.getUninterruptibly(CompletableFutures.java:149) at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.session.SessionBuilder.build(SessionBuilder.java:633) at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.DefaultConnectionFactory$.createSession(CassandraConnectionFactory.scala:144) at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$CassandraConnector$$createSession(CassandraConnector.scala:175) ... 25 more Suppressed: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ConnectionInitException: [s0|control|connecting...] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): failed to send request (java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException) at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ProtocolInitHandler$InitRequest.fail(ProtocolInitHandler.java:342) at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ChannelHandlerRequest.writeListener(ChannelHandlerRequest.java:87) at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:577) at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:551) at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:490) at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.addListener(DefaultPromise.java:183) at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:95) at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:30) at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ChannelHandlerRequest.send(ChannelHandlerRequest.java:76) at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ProtocolInitHandler$InitRequest.send(ProtocolInitHandler.java:183) at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ProtocolInitHandler.onRealConnect(ProtocolInitHandler.java:118) at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ConnectInitHandler.lambda$connect$0(ConnectInitHandler.java:57) at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:577) at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:570) at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:549) at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:490) at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:615) at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:608) at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:117) at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.fulfillConnectPromise(AbstractNioChannel.java:321) at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:337) at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:702) at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650) at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576) at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ... 1 more Suppressed: com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:9042 Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:714) at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:330) at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334) at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:702) at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650) at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576) at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.newClosedChannelException(AbstractChannel.java:957) at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0(AbstractChannel.java:921) at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.flush0(AbstractNioChannel.java:354) at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush(AbstractChannel.java:897) at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.flush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1372) at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:748) at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:740) at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:726) at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.flush(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:127) at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:748) at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWriteAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:763) at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:788) at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:756) at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:806) at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.writeAndFlush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1025) at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannel.java:294) at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ChannelHandlerRequest.send(ChannelHandlerRequest.java:75) ... 20 more
```

Answer (score 0):

AWS Glue does not provide native library support to Cassandra. You need to get Cassandra connector and follow the steps mentioned in [ETL jobs against non-native JDBC data sources](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/use-aws-glue-to-run-etl-jobs-against-non-native-jdbc-data-sources/).

Once you have the jar downloaded from [here](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector) then you can pass to your job and use it in your pyspark script.

Comment: I tried downloading nut not sure if i need to upload everytjing to S3 Bucket and pass the same in Glue Job? Is this the right one? datastax-spark-cassandra-connector-19cc8c0

Comment: you can download the jar from here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector and upload it to s3 as mentioned in the doc for non-native JDBC sources

Comment: Yes i did it, uploaded to S3 bucket and given path to AWS Glue Job. it still throw an error.

Comment: Does your glue iam role has access to the S3 bucket that you uploaded the jar?

Comment: Yes it has access to it as i wrote some files to s3 using different glue jobs. updated the error in my main question

Comment: the error indicates that you are not able to reach cassandra . the security groups that you  configured allows this port used with db?